# Display countdown somewhere in background (Swift )

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I try to display my countdown somewhere on screen **when my app is in background mode**.
I don't know where to put it. I know that we can't display text in status bar. Apparently we can't display a banner below status bar.

I have developed the same app on android. I succeeded by display toasts to the up of the screen.

Do you have ideas ? I remind you that i want display something (banner, toast, etc) with my countdown **when app is in background**.

Comment: Remember you are working on iOS full of privacy. When app is in background you cant show any banner on iPhone. Only way is to provide local notification when timer ends.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in the background the only way to show something is creating a local notification and scheduling to display at certain interval. Think of a reminder for an event. However there is no way to update in realtime such alert (the minimum interval for repeating events is 60 seconds).